# How to select the international telephone input with flags and dial codes dropdown in selenium

Tags: selenium, dropdown

In [this website](https://dancekar.com/parent-center/register)
how to select the international telephone input with flags and dial codes dropdown in selenium, for cellphone field. The selenium code is not selecting

Code I wrote.

```
<div class="control-group ">
    <label class="control-label required" for="CellPhone">Cell Phone</label>
    <div class="controls">
      <input class="form-control phone-number" data-val="true" data-val-intltel="Invalid number" data-val-required="The Cell Phone field is required." id="CellPhone" name="CellPhone" type="text" value="" />
      <span class="help-block">
        <span class="field-validation-valid" data-valmsg-for="CellPhone" data-valmsg-replace="true"></span>
      </span>
    </div>
  </div>


package testing123;





import java.util.List;

import org.openqa.selenium.By;
import org.openqa.selenium.JavascriptExecutor;
import org.openqa.selenium.Keys;
import org.openqa.selenium.WebDriver;
import org.openqa.selenium.WebElement;
import org.openqa.selenium.chrome.ChromeDriver;
import org.openqa.selenium.interactions.Actions;
import org.openqa.selenium.support.ui.Select;


public class dancekarwebsite1 {
    


    public static void main(String[] args) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        
        
        System.setProperty("webdriver.chrome.driver", "C:\\Users\\Vpatiballa\\Desktop\\Lib\\chromedriver.exe");
        WebDriver driver = new ChromeDriver();
        driver.get("https://dancekar.com/parent-center/register");
        driver.manage().window().maximize();
        
        //*[@id="Email"]
        
        //Actions actions = new Actions(driver);

          // Scroll Down using Actions class
         // actions.keyDown(Keys.CONTROL).sendKeys(Keys.END).perform();
        JavascriptExecutor js = (JavascriptExecutor) driver;
        js.executeScript("window.scrollBy(0,250)", "");
        
    //driver.findElement(By.xpath("//div[@class='selected-flag']")).click();
        
    
    
    
    Actions action = new Actions(driver);    
    WebElement optionsList = driver.findElement(By.xpath("//div[@class='selected-flag']"));
    action.moveToElement(optionsList);

    List<WebElement> options = driver.findElements(By.xpath("//div[@class='selected-flag']"));
    for(WebElement option : options) {
        if (option.getText().equals("United Kingdom +44")) {
            option.click();
        }
    }
    
    
    
    
    
    
    
    
    }
    }
```

Comment: Is your issue solved?

Answer (score 0):

1. You should click on your flag to open dropdown, you use `action.moveToElement` but that doesn't perfom a click and doesn't open dropdown. Try:

   ```
   action.moveToElement(optionsList).build().perform();
   ```
2. You may need wait till dropdown is opened.
3. To get list of elements use:

   ```
   List<WebElement> options = driver.findElements(By.cssSelector(".country .country-name"));
   ```